# Что означает функция runEquals()?

Tags: javascript

```js
function run1() {

  document.case.display.value += "1"
};

function run2() {

  document.case.display.value += "2"
};

function run3() {

  document.case.display.value += "3"
};

function run4() {

  document.case.display.value += "4"
};

function run5() {

  document.case.display.value += "5"
};

function run6() {

  document.case.display.value += "6"
};

function run7() {

  document.case.display.value += "7"
};

function run8() {

  document.case.display.value += "8"
};

function run9() {

  document.case.display.value += "9"
};

function run0() {

  document.case.display.value += "0"
};

function runPlus() {

  document.case.display.value += "+"
};

function runMinus() {

  document.case.display.value += "-"
};

function runDivide() {

  document.case.display.value += "/"
};

function runMultiply() {

  document.case.display.value += "*"
};

function runC() {

  document.case.display.value = ""
};


function runEquals() {
  var equals = eval(document.case.display.value)
  document.case.display.value = equals;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css" title="calc.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="calc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="case">
    <input name="display" id="display" value="">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="1" onclick="run1()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="2" onclick="run2()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="3" onclick="run3()">
    <input type="button" id="plus" class="oper" value="+" onclick="runPlus()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="4" onclick="run4()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="5" onclick="run5()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="6" onclick="run6()">
    <input type="button" id="minus" class="oper" value="-" onclick="runMinus()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="7" onclick="run7()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="8" onclick="run8()">
    <input type="button" class="digit" value="9" onclick="run9()">
    <input type="button" id="divide" class="oper" value="/" onclick="runDivide()">

    <input type="button" class="digit" value="0" onclick="run0()">
    <input type="button" id="clearMem" class="oper" value="C" onclick="runC()">


    <input type="button" id="equal" class="oper" value="=" onclick="runEquals()">
    <input type="button" id="multiply" class="oper" value="*" onclick="runMultiply()">

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: у вас там все кнопки калькулятора поименованы, неужели не можете перевести что значит `equal`, хотя бы со словарем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функцией [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) интерпретируется выражение в `#display`, после чего в него же отправляется результат.

А код писал мсье с большой фантазией, рефакторить и рефакторить.

Comment: чего там рефакторить то? все функции удалить, одну оставить, дата атрибуты прописать. фантазии у автора ноль, зато упорства не занимать.

Comment: @teran, ну вот Вы и перечислили что там рефакторить :)

Comment: _"рефакторить и рефакторить"_ это когда долго и нудно, а тут `ctrl+A` => `del` :D

Comment: @teran, ну удаление тоже входит в расстояние Левенштейна, так что можно и `Delete` :)